# How to load anaconda virtual environment from slurm?

Tags: bash, anaconda, environment, slurm

I set up anaconda on the VM where slurm is installed as follows.

```
base                     /root/anaconda3
upload                *  /root/anaconda3/envs/upload
```

And the file in slurm is:

```
#SBATCH -J vs_slurm_upload
#SBATCH -o ./out/%j_log.out
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --array=0-14
FILES=(../workdir/*)

pwd
conda info --envs
source activate upload
```

However, unlike the Anaconda settings I set, there is no upload virtual environment.

Here is the result:

```
base                     /root/anaconda3
```

In order to set the virtual environment in slurm, do I need to set docker instead of setting it in my VM?

I don't quite understand slurm yet.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: The locations Conda checks for envs is sourced from multiple locations, but most relevant here is likely the user local file `~/.condarc`. You likely need to specify to SLURM to run the script as your user and not a blank shell (e.g., `bash -l`).

Comment: @merv Perhaps the problem is this isn't it. I added `bash -l` to my sh file but I get the same problem.
When executing the `$PATH` command
`local: bash
slurm: /var/spool/slurmd/job21697/slurm_script`
Is there any other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is perhaps because the user-specific `~/.condarc` is not being loaded due to not running the SLURM script in login mode (i.e., as your user). Try modifying the script to something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash -l

#SBATCH -J vs_slurm_upload
#SBATCH -o ./out/%j_log.out
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --array=0-14
FILES=(../workdir/*)

pwd
conda info --envs
conda activate upload
```

Note that I also changed the `source activate` to `conda activate` - the former syntax has been deprecated since Conda v4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Bash will not source profile scripts from /etc/profile.d/*.sh unless you supply `-l`. I solved this by making a slurm prologue script instead, see https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3794

Comment: This answer would be improved by describing here - at least in outline - the info found in the link.

Comment: @merv There isn't much more to it though. Link is not directly related to conda. But what conda init adds to your .bashrc is all you need to add to the prologue script